# JavaScript substring from begin to first space

Tags: javascript

```
const title=document.title;
const id = title.substring(0,title.indexOf(' '));
```

Can these two lines be more concise? What is the best practice to get substring from begin to first space

Comment: *"Best practice"* is, sometimes, quite subjective. But, regarding the code golf, this wins: `title.split(" ")[0]`

Comment: By default `indexOf` returns the position of the first appearance of the searching string is available.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado technically ``title.split` `[0]`` wins the code golf

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, it does!

Comment: I would argue split is probably what most people would want in this case. If there is no space it will still work, `str = 'Prince'; str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' '))` will not.

Answer (score 6):

[Reference split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

You can using **split()** method

```
const id = title.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: No reference, no explanation, no nothing except the solution. Please explain what your code is doing and add reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `split()` function. The split function breaks the whole string in the form of array. In the code give below, the variable `title` contains string `'Muhammad Usman'`, so the function `split()` breaks the string in the form or an array in `'id'` variable. Therefore the 0-th index of id, `id[0]` contains the value `'Muhammad'` & index 1 of id `id[1]` contains the value `'Usman'`.

I'm attaching the output of the code which prints the first string before the space.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     const title="Muhammad Usman";

     const id=title.split(' ')[0];
     document.write("id :" + id);

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: Output of the code]